# Android access menu from onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following in my activity (sorry new to Java/Android):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.selectItem:
            // menu.add(...) --> how to get the menu instance?
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am wondering, how can I access a menu object in onOptionsItemSelected? For example, how would I go about adding a new view to the options menu based on the selection of an existing menu item? Is the answer related to "onPrepareOptionsMenu"?

Answer (score 1):

you should use [SubMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#submenu) for such things ... remeber that you cant add submenu to another submenu ... so only Menu->Submenu is possible you can't do stuff like this Menu->Submenu->Submenu (while Submenu is Dialog with choices)

Comment: what I really want to do is probably more simple than I am making it sound... when an item is selected, I want to set this selected item .setVisible(false) and I want to make a search box visible. Like when you click on the magnifying glass in gmail, then it changes to a search box...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/ edit this is for api 11 better go here C:\android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-9\SearchableDictionary

Comment: awesome... ended up implementing the searchWidget. Perfect solution.